# Toggleclass hide show multiple angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework

How can I toggle classes on several elements individually with ng-click?

I would like to hide / show but Both inputs get show if I press one.

```js
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.custom = true;
        $scope.ShowHide = function() {
            $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
        };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-checkbox">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="on" ng-click="ShowHide()">
                    </label>
                   Test1
</div>
<div class="item range range-positive" ng-hide="custom">
                 
    <input type="range"  min="0" max="10"   step="1" >
                  
</div>
<div class="item item-checkbox">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="on" ng-click="ShowHide()">
                    </label>
                   Test2
</div>
<div class="item range range-positive" ng-hide="custom">
                 
    <input type="range"  min="0" max="10"   step="1" >
                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because currently you are referring to same variable which name is `custom`, so by changing `custom` value anywhere will hide both element which has `ng-hide="custom"`. You should have different name for those variables.

It would be better if you render your all templates using `ng-repeat`, so that will also make less work while toggling flags. As you could have `ng-model` over check-box directly & then apply that checkbox `ng-model` which `item.show`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item item-checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="on" ng-model="item.show">
        </label> Test1
    </div>
    <div class="item range range-positive" ng-hide="item.show">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" ng-model="item.range"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.items = [
    {Id: 1, Value: true, range: 1 }, //Value true will make checkbox check by default
    {Id: 2, show: true, Range: 1 },
    {Id: 3, show: true, range: 1 },
    {Id: 4, show: true, range: 1 },
    {Id: 5, show: true, range: 1 },
    {Id: 6, show: true, range: 1 },
    {Id: 7, show: true, range: 1 },
]
```

Comment: like that have 10 items can i give  individual variable

Comment: @sridharan then why don't use `ng-repeat` to render them all? then this thing will become super simple

Comment: i new to angularjs how can use ng-repeat

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geniuscarrier/tKZjZ/ this the link i referred but i need multiple buttons

Comment: if have any option like jquery $(this)

Comment: @sridharan why..you want `$(this)`?